# Two colours in one node with graphviz's dot?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm wondering if it is possible to split a node into two different colours.
I'm using graphviz's dot (http://www.graphviz.org/).

Perhaps a verticle, or diagonal line could split the node into two colours. I want to do this because I have many nodes which belong to two different categories (colours) with some nodes belonging to both.

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Gradient functionality](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dfillcolor) was only added to Graphviz on January 26, 2012; until the new 2.30.0 stable version of Graphviz is released, you'll need to [download Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Download.php) development version 2.29.20120127.0545 or newer.

In addition, gradients seem to only be implemented for the Cairo/Pango renderer so far; in my tests, the Quartz (Mac) and GD renderers fall back to using just the first color. In particular, this means if you're on a Mac and are using the Graphviz.app GUI viewer, you won't see gradients there (yet).

```
digraph G {
  Gradient [style="filled", fillcolor="orange:yellow"]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks (just a bit late perahps!). Now I have updated my Graphviz I shall have a look at this :)

Comment: Somehow doesn't work for me. I tried v2.40.1 on Mac OS, and a web-based Graphviz tool.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box solution to have 2 background colors.

The best solution would be to use **[gradient](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#kcolorList)** fills (`fillcolor="orange:yellow"`) - but though this is in the documentation, I wasn't able to make it work on my box.

You could use **[HTML-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/content/node-shapes#html)** as a workaround. You may need to split the label to have it centered, depending on your needs:

```
a[shape="none", label=<
<table cellpadding="0" cellborder="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="orange">abc</td>
<td bgcolor="yellow">def</td>
</tr>
</table>
>]
```

[image: 2 colors]

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. The gradient sounds perfect although like you, I could not get it working either.  The HTML label works well, thank you. I'll just wait to see if anyone knows if the gradient works properly or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, if you use the `image` attribute of a label and provide a suitable background image:

```
digraph G {
  i1 [shape=none, image="range.png", label=""];
  i2 [shape=none, image="range.png", label="Image w label", imagescale=true];
  i1 -> i2;
}
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

using the `range.png` file

[image]