# graphViz: how to assign multiple color to nodes

Tags: graphviz

I want to assign multiple color to a node in graphViz. the optimal solution would be a circular node with a pie chart format.

I know one way which is to use HTML tag. the following is a simple example:

```
graph G{
    1--2;
    1[shape=none,margin=0,label=< 
    <table BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4"> 
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="red"></td>
            <td bgcolor="blue"></td>
        </tr>   
     </table>         >];
    2[shape=circle,style=filled,fillcolor=yellow];
    3[shape=circle,style=filled,fillcolor=yellow];
}
```

**However**, there are some problems:

1. the node 1 has no label (I want it to have label "1" )
2. the edge connecting the node 1 to node 2 is not completely attached to node 1. In other words, there is a space between node 1 and the edge connecting it to node 2.
3. node 1 is rectangular. how can I have a circular node?

If there is no way to overcome these problems, would you please suggest any other graph visualization software?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by

```
graph G{
    1--2;
    1[shape=circle,style=wedged,fillcolor="red:blue"];
    2[shape=circle,style=filled,fillcolor=yellow];
    3[shape=circle,style=filled,fillcolor=yellow];
}
```

The advantage of the approach is that you can use more than 2 colors in a node.

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st problem, it really depends on your implementation for the two-color nodes. You have multiple solutions described in this post: [Two colours in one node with graphviz's dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025215/two-colours-in-one-node-with-graphvizs-dot) With your current code, the easiest way to add a label is to write it inside ot the `<td></td>` tags, like in the following code:

```
graph G{
    1--2;
    1[shape=none,margin=0,label=< 
    <table BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4"> 
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="red">1</td>
            <td bgcolor="blue"></td>
        </tr>   
     </table>         >];
    2[shape=circle,style=filled,fillcolor=yellow];
    3[shape=circle,style=filled,fillcolor=yellow];
}
```

However, it won't be centered, and I think a gradient node is preferrable.

For your second problem, you need to declare a port on the cells of your array, and use them to anchor your edges when drawing edges:

```
graph G{
    1[shape=none, label=< 
    <table MARGIN="0" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4"> 
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="red" port="L">1</td>
            <td bgcolor="blue" port="R"></td>
        </tr>   
     </table>         >];
    2[shape=circle,style=filled,fillcolor=yellow];
    3[shape=circle,style=filled,fillcolor=yellow];
    1:L--2;
}
```

For your 3rd problem, according to http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html, you have the possibility to create custom shapes. I don't know any way to create such rounded arrays, so you should look in this direction I think.